# using sed for substitution in next line

Tags: sed

I am working on sed command to translate some text into another text.

cat text

```
           &lt;strong&gt;ABC
           &lt;/strong&gt;
```

Commnad:

```
           sed -e 's|&lt;strong&gt;(.*?)&lt;/strong&gt;|//textbf{1}|g'
```

Expected Outcome:  \textbf{ABC}

but using above script i cannot convert it into  expected output since there is new line between the tags. How to handle such cases?

Comment: Use `n` or `N` to build multi-line pattern spaces with sed.

Comment: I used   sed -ne 's|&lt;strong&gt;(.*?)&lt;/strong&gt;|//textbf{1}|g' text but i get no output.

Comment: Not `-n`, the `N` goes within the sed command. Here's a link with details on working with multiple lines in sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;s|(&lt;)(strong&gt;)([^\n]*)\n\s*\1/\2|//textbf{\3}|;P;D' file
```

or

```
sed '$!N;s|\(&lt;\)\(strong&gt;\)\([^\n]*\)\n\s*\1/\2|//textbf{\3}|;P;D' file
```

Comment: I have strong as br with in strong like &lt;strong&gt;ABC stroke&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;/strong&gt;  , i m bit confused to use the above as it is nested.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 'N;s|&lt;strong&gt;\(.*\?\)\n&lt;/strong&gt;|\/textbf{\1}|g'
```

as said by CodeGnome and David Ravetti, the N flag allows for multi-line patterns.

Comment: I m using sed -e 'N;s|&lt;strong&gt;\(.*\?\)\n&lt;/strong&gt;|\/textbf{\1}|g'  text but still no change.

Comment: You are missing the \ in front of (.

Comment: @cdbitesky - in your example you have `\?` ... is that intentional? Seems it would search for a literal "?" when I think the intent of the OP was to  make the `(.*)` portion optional (which I don't think is necessary since the "*" should match zero or more).

Comment: I think \? might not be necessary. I just need to match anything within tag.

Comment: My version of sed uses ? as literal '?' and \? has the regex character. I'm not sure why.